# Change moment date string into proper timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date with time and a timezone.

I need this formatted a specific way, which is why I am using moment.

Say the date string I want to put in is `2018-12-31 02:00:00.000 +00:00`

I convert it into a specific format doing the following:

```
const properDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:ms')
```

However this is assuming the date is in UTC, and I want it to be in America/New York timezone, so the date and time I am expecting is actually:

> 2018-12-30 21:00:00.000

So my question is, how do I add in the timezone to moment when converting a date/time to a specific format?
I know it isn't as simple as passing a parameter. Is it another function I should call?

I have tried

```
const properDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:ms').tz('America/New_York')
```

but that didn't work either.

Edit: I should also mention that I am also using `moment-timezone`. It just seems that I can't get it to format the way I need it to as well as get it in the proper timezone.

So basically, I would think I could do something like:

```
const momentDate = moment(date)
const properDate = momentDate.tz(timezone).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:ms')
```

Unfortunately as long as I try to format it, it won't work either.

Comment: You have to use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and parse your input using [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/), quite sure it was asked before.

Comment: I looked into this, but the only way I found to do it, I couldn't get it formatted the way I require it to. Basically I guess I need both of these to work together: format it in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:ms` format AND for it to be in the proper timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) for parsing time string using a given timezone (e.g. `'America/New_York'`) while [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) is for converting between zones.

Here a live sample:

```js
const date = '2018-12-30 21:00:00.000';
const properDate = moment.tz(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS', 'America/New_York')
console.log(properDate.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```